# string to date conversion returns NaN

Tags: javascript, datetimepicker, nan

I'm using a jquery datetime picker plugin and have three textboxes viz., startdate, enddate, difference. plugin works perfectly, startdate string (dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm) format gets converted correctly but enddate string doesn't get converted to Date object and it returns NaN. can anyone help  me?
here's my code:-

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#<%= txtEndDate.ClientID %>').bootstrapMaterialDatePicker
            ({
                weekStart: 0, format: 'DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm', shortTime: true
            });
            $('#<%= txtStartDate.ClientID %>').bootstrapMaterialDatePicker
            ({
                weekStart: 0, format: 'DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm', shortTime: true
            }).on('change', function (e, date) {
                $('#<%= txtEndDate.ClientID %>').bootstrapMaterialDatePicker('setMinDate', date);
            });
            $('.mb').change(function () {
                var start = $('#<%= txtStartDate.ClientID %>').val();
                alert('start:-'+start);
                var end1 = $('#<%= txtEndDate.ClientID %>').val();
                alert('end:-'+end1);

                if (start != "" && end1 != "") {
                    var eDate = Date.parse(end1);
                    var sDate = Date.parse(start);

                    alert(sDate);
                    alert(eDate);// gives NaN
                    var diff = Math.abs(eDate - sDate);
                    alert(diff);
                    // get total seconds between the times
                    var delta = diff / 1000;

                    // calculate (and subtract) whole days
                    var days = Math.floor(delta / 86400);
                    delta -= days * 86400;

                    // calculate (and subtract) whole hours
                    var hours = Math.floor(delta / 3600) % 24;
                    delta -= hours * 3600;

                    // calculate (and subtract) whole minutes
                    var minutes = Math.floor(delta / 60) % 60;
                    delta -= minutes * 60;

                    // what's left is seconds
                    var seconds = delta % 60;

                    $('#<%= txtDifference.ClientID %>').val(parseInt(days) + ":" + parseInt(hours) + ":" + parseInt(minutes) + ":" + parseInt(seconds));
                }
            })
        });
    </script>
```

`alert('start:-'+start);` gives start:-12/11/2017 20:52`alert('end:-'+end1);` gives end:-13/11/2017 20:54
`alert(sDate);` gives 1513005720000
`but alert(eDate);` gives NaN

Comment: Can you please post the output of the alert statement ... ?

Comment: @82Tuskers i've updated the question. please take a look.

Comment: I just answered. Just let me know if that works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After some research and getting harassed by `plain javascript` I switched to `moment.js` and voila! I got the result of a valid date difference. I just replaced my javascript code with:-

```
var d1 = moment(startDateString, "DD-MM-YYYY HH:mm");
var d2 = moment(endDateString, "DD-MM-YYYY HH:mm");
```

This worked smoothly.

Answer (score 0):

Date.parse() has some quirky support across browsers. Like some strings parsed on Chrome returns NaN in FF.

So, I suggest writing a utility function that composes your date from the string format you are using.

Here is an regex based snippet to extract the dd, mm and yyyy from the string and compose it to a Date object.

```
function getTimeFromString (formattedString) {
    var a = formattedString.match(/(\d{2})\/(\d{2})\/(\d{4})\s(\d{2}):(\d{2})/)
    var d = new Date()
    d.setDate(a[1]), d.setMonth[a[2] - 1], d.setYear(a[3]), d.setHours(a[4]), d.setMinutes(a[5])
    return d.getTime()
}
```

And, use getTimeFromString to do your calculations. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

This unexpected behavior is probably due to date string format that you are trying to parse. If you look closely at [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse) **dateString** explanation you can see

> A string representing an RFC2822 or (a variant of) ISO 8601 date (other formats may be used, but results may be unexpected).

Also take a look at return value explained

> If the argument doesn't represent a valid date, NaN is returned.

So, I have tried following and got `1513022040000` as result. Hope it helps

```
var dateString = new Date('12/11/2017 20:54');
var result = Date.parse(dateString);
console.log(result)
```